# Athena Dont Query Non-Parquet data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-athena

Data in s3 bucket contain parquet files as well as files in other formats like xml,crc,json etc..
I would like to query only parquet data.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test`()
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION
  's3:/some location/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
 'classification'='parquet', 
 'created_by'='system', 
 'has_encrypted_data'='true')
```

below mentioned query giving me error

```
SELECT * FROM "test" limit 10;
```

***Error Text:
**HIVE_BAD_DATA: Not valid Parquet file: s3://some location/control_file.ctl expected magic number: PAR1 got: c8*****

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Amazon Athena will attempt to read *every file* in the given directory, including its subdirectories.

Comment: Do you have any answer to above question? Or you just have an comment ?

Answer (score 0):

If there is any pattern that you can use to recognize parquet files, try to limit to read the files as: select * from test where regex_like("$path", '.parquet')

PS: In the above query I assumed parquet files have .parquet in their file names. I did not test it.